# Unit Testing iOS App which used Alamofire for network request

Tags: ios, unit-testing, uiviewcontroller, alamofire, stub

I am new to iOS Development and I am building an app which uses Alamofire for HTTP request. I need to write Unit test for few things like login and need help with it. I did some research about Stub, Mocks and also read about few frameworks like Nocilla and OHTTPStubs but I am unable to get started. I have a login controller which gets login information like - username, password from storyboard and on login button action I call a server utility method. I have a server utility class which implements the method for making network request.

```
@IBAction func logIn(sender: AnyObject?) {

    server.loginWith(username, password: password, server:url) { (user, error) in
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            if let err = error {
                self.handleError(err)
                return
            }
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("unwind", sender: self)
        }
    }
}
```

This is server utility class

```
class Server {
func loginWith(username:String, password:String, server:String, callback:CompleteHandler) {
    Alamofire.request(.GET, server + "/login", headers:defaultHeaders).validate().responseJSON {response in
        var err:NSError?
        var user:Object?
        defer {
            dispatch_group_leave(self.dispGrp)
            callback(user:user, error: err)
        }

        switch response.result {
        case .Success():
            //gives me user data

        case .Failure(let error):
           // gives me error
    }
}
```

How do I Unit test the following code provided I do not wish to make a network call. Please help me as I am stuck since long.

Thank you.

Comment: As you mentioned to stub network calls(HTTP/HTTPS), you can start with [Stubby DB](https://github.com/NaturalIntelligence/StubbyDB). Link for [Video tutorial](https://youtu.be/7mA4-MXxwgk). It can help you to test error cases, various response codes, delay call etc.

Answer (score 1):

use [OHHTTPStubs](https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHHTTPStubs)

Its allow you to :

- test your apps with fake network data (stubbed from file) and simulate slow networks, to check your application behavior in bad network conditions
- write unit tests that use fake network data from your fixtures.

And [support swift 3.0](https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHHTTPStubs/releases/tag/5.2.1-swift3) too

Comment: Can you give me an example on how to use OHHTTPStubs with the code I gave? It would be really helpful.